# Multiple possible data types in a single Django model field?

Tags: python, django, model, polymorphism

## TLDR

One of my models contains data that could either be a charfield, textfield, or boolfield based on a choice made in a separate model that it is connected to through a foreignkey. What's the most efficient way to model this in Django?

## My problem

I'm putting together a Django app that outputs a python {'key': 'value'} dictionary in a somewhat lengthy two-step process. In the first step, users design a custom 'Template' that contains a collection of 'TemplateEntries'. In pseudo-code:

```
Template MODEL  
foreign key: User  
description = textfield  
name = charfield  

TemplateEntry MODEL  
foreign key: Template  
key = charfield  
value_type = charfield(choices='CharField', 'TextField', 'BoolField')  
description = textfield  
order = positivesmallintegerfield (So users can re-arrange the order of TemplateEntries when creating the Template)
```

EXAMPLE TEMPLATE FORM #1

1. [Description] | [Key] | Field Type: [Choice between **Char Field**, Text Field, Bool Field]
2. [Description] | [Key] | Field Type: [Choice between **Char Field**, Text Field, Bool Field]
3. [Description] | [Key] | Field Type: [Choice between Char Field, Text Field, **Bool Field**]
4. [Description] | [Key] | Field Type: [Choice between **Char Field**, Text Field, Bool Field]
5. [Description] | [Key] | Field Type: [Choice between Char Field, **Text Field**, Bool Field]

In the second step, the same or different user is presented with a form based off of the Template and with the appropriate field for each of the values. In pseudocode:

```
EntrySet MODEL  
foreignkey: User  
foreignkey: Template  
name = charfield

Entry MODEL  
foreignkey: EntrySet  
foreignkey: TemplateEntry  
value = ??
```

EXAMPLE ENTRYSET FORM FOR TEMPLATE #1
(the description for what entry represents is carried over from TemplateEntry)

1. [Char Field]
2. [Char Field]
3. True/False (Bool Field)
4. [Char Field]
5. [----------------Text Field-----------------]

Finally, the dictionary is created by combining the key field from each TemplateEntry in Template with the value field from each Entry in EntrySet.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to model the 'value' field in the entry model, since it could take the form of a charfield, textfield, or boolfield. My current approach is to break it up into three different fields: value_short = charfield, value_long = textfield, value_bool = boolfield and to iterate through each of them when creating the dictionary, only taking the value of whichever field has content. However, this seems inefficient and would result in errors if more than one of them contained a value. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue or improve my model would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database supports [jsonfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) and you want to keep it as a single field, you can use it.

If it doesn't, first of all, if I'm not skipping something, you can use both textfield and charfield as textfield instead of separating them. Other than that, the best option is to leave these fields with the options `null=True,blank=True`. Then, add data to the relevant field according to its type and return whichever is not null to the user. And if you need to nullify the previous value when the data type changes, I recommend you do it in view or form or in pre_save signal.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that `contenttypes` will be useful for you, and help you to prevent reinventing the wheel:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have to admit I don't fully understand contenttypes but I think getting it to work with my project would require me to create three separate models for each of the data types I am storing, which would be no less complicated than storing them within multiple fields of a single model.

Comment: Yes, if you want to store the data with a high level of normalization, that's some of the cost you have to pay.